# Script Change .sh for Windows Server 2008

Tags: iis, powershell, migration, windows-server-2008

I try to do a migration to Windows Server 2008 and i am new with script concept.

I have a .sh file to launch which contains :

```
cd RADIOROOT/PLAYERS
killall player_1
su - robotstream --command='/RADIOROOT/PLAYERS/player_1 -t /RADIOROOT/PLAYERS/player_1.conf' & > dev/null
```

First, how can i launch this .sh file on my IIS ? Do i have to change it in a powershell script ?

I tried to change it to a .ps1 file with some changes but not working. Anyone know how to do it ?

Then, do you have any website about changing this sort of script in order to make it work ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure `robotstream` software supports Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything is the same on the Windows server as it was on your *nix server (same paths, robotstream takes the same arguments, etc) this should do the same thing in PowerShell:

```
cd C:\RADIOROOT\PLAYERS
Stop-Process player_1
$command = "robotstream --command='/RADIOROOT/PLAYERS/player_1 -t /RADIOROOT/PLAYERS/player_1.conf'"
Invoke-Expression $command
```

Save that with a .ps1 extension, and then run it from a PowerShell console.

As far as a website about converting SH scripts to PowerShell, you'll need to learn Bash (so you can understand the script you're converting), and PowerShell (so you know how to write the new script). There are plenty of good websites out there for both. Just Google "powershell tutorial".

Hope that helps. Feel free to ask for clarification.